# What is the difference between 役割 & 業務タイトル?

Tags: nuances, nouns, business-japanese

Both of these terms are found in the same `職務経歴書`.

After attempting to translate the terms used in an [example](http://www.victorayechan.com/2014/08/20/the-japanese-resume-shokumukeirekisho/),
I've come to the following hypothesis:

`業務タイトル` - Department in a company

`役割` - One's specific position

In English resumes, we usually refer to one's position as a `[Job] Title, Position, Role`.  Thus, the use of `タイトル` has caused me some confusion.

**Is my conclusion correct**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the provided example one more time,

`業務タイトル` - Project Title

One definition of `業務` is `task`, a synonym for `project` or `assignment`.

Comment: Yes, 業務タイトル should be something like "Building the database infrastructure of a high-traffic e-commerce site". Japanese タイトル almost never refers to one's position such as "manager" or "designer".